# How to find the orthogonal complement and the expression of the image of the orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $I=[-1,1]$, $Q=I\times I=[-1,1]^2$, $B=L^2(I,\mathcal{B_I},\lambda_1)$, $H=L^2(Q,\mathcal{B}_{Q},\lambda_2).$
Consider the set $$V=\{u\in H|\exists v\in B, \text{s.t.}~u(x,y)=v(x)~\text{a.e.}~(x,y)\in Q\}.$$

(1) Find the orthogonal complement $V^\bot$.

(2) Letting $P_V$ denote the orthogonal projection, find the expression of $P_Vu$ for all $u\in H$.

(3) Let $u(x,y)=xy$, find $P_Vu$.

I have found that $V$ is a closed subspace of $H$, but then how to find the expression of the image of the orthogonal projection? I don't even know how to express the form of the orthogonal complement the orthogonal complement?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** First observe that if $\int_Iu(x,y)dy=0$ for almost every $x\in I$, then $u\perp V$.

Then define
$$Q:B\to H\ \quad Q(v)=(x,y)\mapsto v(x)\\
P:H\to B\ \quad P(u)=x\mapsto\int_Iu(x,y)dy$$
And prove that they are adjoint to each other.

Comment: Then how to find or which is the $P_V(u)$?

Comment: The projection is basically $P$, specifically just $Q\circ P$.